# MultiLineText DataType Value not populating in TextAreaFor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am attempting to implement an Update on a current text area value.

The datatype is set for multiline in my model

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

When the page loads for the textarea, it does not populate.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.Text, new { @Value = Model.Text })
```

But for a textbox it does populate

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Text, new { @Value = Model.Text })
```

Is there something I'm missing? this seems pretty straight forward.

[image: it should work like this]

[image]

Comment: edited so I don't get yelled at

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723028/replacement-for-textareafor-code-in-asp-net-mvc-razor?rq=1

Comment: no, that is not what I'm looking for, the Model.Text value needs to populate inside the textbox

Comment: @Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.Text) should be enough - MVC takes care of populate value for textarea

Comment: Never ever set the `value` attribute when using a `HtmlHelper` method. And a `<textarea>` does not have a `value` attribute. And `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` is only respected when using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Text)` - which will then correctly generate your `<textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.Text,  new { id = "SomeID", placeholder = "Text", Value = Model.Text})
```

Comment: Value should already be populated in the text area as if it was a placeholder, a user would be able to edit what is in the text area

Comment: Was taking a shot in the dark.  Really would need to see more code.  Definitely is helpful

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.UserName)` should be enough - ASP MVC takes care of populate current value from model to textarea. 
Using `{ @Value = Model.Text }` doesn't apply to textarea as it does not uses value attribute: [How to add default value for html <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007219/how-to-add-default-value-for-html-textarea)